# Can a relation that is NOT a function be one-to-one or onto?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Let $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B = \{7,8,9\}$. For the relation between $A$ and $B$  given as a subset of $A \times B = \{(1,9), (1,7), (3,8)\}$, $A\times B$ is not a function because $1$ appears as the first element in more than one ordered pair. This made me think about the following *generalized* question.

If a relation is not a function,  then it is only a subset of $A$ and $B$ denoted as $A\times B$. Then can this subset be one-to-one? Can it be onto?

**One-to-One?:** Even though $A\times B$ is not a function, I believe it satisfies the requirements of being one-to-one because in $A$, $x_1 = x_2$ only when $x_1 = x_1$.

**Onto?:**  I want to say yes also. The range of $A$ could be the range of $B$. If $A \times B = \{(1,9), (1,8), (3,8)\}$, then does this satisfy the requirement of being onto?

Basically what is piquing my curiosity is if non-function relations can be one-to-one or onto or if being one-to-one and/or onto **implies** that it must be a function.

Comment: Your notation is a bit confused. A relation is a subset $R$ of the Cartesian product $A\times B$. In your example, $|A\times B| = 3\times 3 = 9$, but the relation you are describing is only a subset of that set of $9$ elements.

Comment: Hmm. This is how my professor wrote the question down. "For each relation between $A$ and $B$ given as a subset of $A\times B$, decide whether it is a function mapping $A$ into $B$. 

I see that $|A\times B|$ should equal 9, but maybe my professor only wanted a subset of the relation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer here is *yes*, relations which are not functions can also be described as injective or surjective. [You can read more about it on the wikipedia page here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) under the section titled "Special types of binary relations," but the definitions are the natural ones:

> A relation $R\subset A\times B$ is *injective* if for all $a,a'\in A$ and $b\in B$, $(a,b)\in R$ and $(a',b)\in R$ implies $a = a'$.
>
> A relation $R\subset A\times B$ is *surjective* if for each $b\in B$, there is some $a\in A$ such that $(a,b)\in R$.

Some examples will hopefully clarify:

- If $A = \{\mathbf{1}\}$, a singleton with one element, and $B = \{\mathbf 1,\mathbf 2,\mathbf 3\}$, then the relation $R = \{(\mathbf 1,\mathbf 1), (\mathbf 1,\mathbf 2), (\mathbf 1,\mathbf 3)\}$ is both injective and surjective, and it is not a function.
- If $A = \{\mathbf 1,\mathbf 2,\mathbf 3\}$, $B = \{\mathbf 1,\mathbf 2\}$, then the relation $R = \{(\mathbf 1,\mathbf 1), (\mathbf 2,\mathbf 1)\}$ is not injective, not surjective, and it is not a function.
- If $A = B = \Bbb Z$, the set of integers, and $R = \emptyset \subset A\times B$ is the empty set, then $R$ is injective (hint: [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)), it is not surjective, and it is a function ([vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) again).
- If $A = \Bbb R$, the set of real numbers, $B = \Bbb R_{\ge 0}$, the set of non-negative real numbers, and $R\subset A\times B$ is the relation $R=\{(x,x^2): x\in \Bbb R\}$, then $R$ is a surjective function, but it is not injective.

Comment: ahhh great! So in a way, a function is basically a subset of a binary relation!

Comment: @EvanKim: Functions are a special case of relations, which are merely subsets of the Cartesian product $A\times B$. The defining feature of functions is that *corresponding to each* element of the domain, is a *unique* element in the codomain.

Comment: Great, thanks for the edit too. I will be sure to read more about binary relations and review your examples again

Comment: dear Alex, +1, but forgive me if I'm being dense: isn't the relation $R$ in your first bullet point injective? indeed, if $A$ is a singleton, then I think any relation from $A$ to *any* set $B$ will be injective

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom: Thanks for catching that! I corrected the example and also added one more example of a relation that is not injective.